# text field in file upload servlet, Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my java application i am uploading multiple files using java servlet.
All things works fine until i added extra text field in my form.

I am getting null document when i add text field.

Here is my code:-

JSP Form:-

```
<form action="upload/servlet"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Upload File:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
                </td>
                <td style="color: red; font-style: italic;"><form:errors
                        path="file" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Generate Key</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href="generateWebKey.do"><input type="button" value="Change Key"/></a>
                </td>
                <td>${key}</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Zip Code</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="100001" name="zipcode"/>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

 </form>
```

Here is my servlet:-

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,"Multipart content expected!");
    }
     ModelMap model = new ModelMap();

    try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<FileItem> files = this.upload.parseRequest(req);
        String userName=req.getSession().getAttribute("username").toString();
        String fileName;
        String contentType;
        byte[] content;
        System.out.print("Zipcode is "+req.getParameter("zipcode"));
        for(FileItem item : files) {
            if(item.isFormField()){
            fileName = item.getName();
            contentType = item.getContentType();
            content = item.get();
            String id=this.indexDocument(fileName, contentType, content,userName,req);
            model.put(id, fileName);
            System.out.println("Done for  "+fileName+ "   id   "+id);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        System.out.println("Error FileUploadException: "+e.getMessage());
        throw new ServletException(e);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
    }

    req.setAttribute("message", model);
    req.getSession().setAttribute("tmpRetMessage", model);
//  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/success.do");
    //dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    resp.sendRedirect("../success.do");
}
```

If i add two text fields then getting null document error two times. If i add three times then getting error three times.

Comment: `req.getAttribute("zipcode")`?

Comment: Sorry it's getParameter.

Comment: Can i ask whats wrong in my question, So i can improve again next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here form `enctype` type `multipart` (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`). So `request.getParameter()` value will be `null`. So you need to process `file` field and regular fields means other than `file` like `text`, `radio`, etc separately.

[see for more how to get request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Thanks. Something is working now. Now i am getting value by 'item.getFieldName()', But in this we cant pass parameter, So i tried to get field name and field value seprately, then i will add condition according to filed name. But i am able to get filed value not field name. 'item.getName()' returning null.

Comment: Got it. We need to use getString not getName. Thanks for the help.